# OpenGL Compute shader lockup after glMapBuffer

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

I am doing a simple cloth simulation based on some existing code and am working on OpenGL 4.3 profile. The problem I am facing is that I am trying to incorporate a simple compute shader which takes in a buffer and just adds some value to it.

Once its done, I map the buffer and then unmap it. After the first 3 frames, the glDispatchCompute locks up. However, if I comment out the map & unmap, it seems to run fine. I tried getting error codes but its returning 0 for every frame. Any ideas on what could be going wrong ??

```
    glUseProgram(computeShader);
    glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, cloth1.vertex_vbo_storage); // Buffer Binding 1
    glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, cloth1.particles.size() * sizeof(Particle), &(cloth1.particles[0]), GL_DYNAMIC_COPY);
    glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, cloth1.vertex_vbo_storage);

    glDispatchCompute(6, 6, 1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cloth1.vertex_vbo_storage);
    Particle * ptr = reinterpret_cast<Particle *>(glMapBufferRange(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, cloth1.particles.size() * sizeof(Particle), GL_MAP_READ_BIT));

    {
        GLenum err = glGetError();
        if (err > 0)
        {
            std::string name = std::string((char*)(glGetString(err)));
        }
    }

    //// memcpy(&cloth1.particles[0], ptr, cloth1.particles.size()*sizeof(Particle));
    glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I was missing an unbind of the GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER between the dispatch.

```
    glDispatchCompute(6, 6, 1);

    **glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, 0);**

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cloth1.vertex_vbo_storage);
```